# Trying to make a subroutine in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have an assignment to make a subroutine with these requirements:

> □  Make a new workbook
> □   Copy the table contained in the ‘2. Formatting’ tab in the Excel file
> □   Paste the table into a new workbook
> □   Rename the worksheet tab in the new workbook to ‘Table Data’
> □   Save the new workbook to the folder created on the desktop using the following name: "_  Excel Assessment VBA"
> □   Save the workbook as a macro-enabled worksheet
> □   Make the folder path universal so other people can create this folder too
> □   Within the file title, add today’s date using the date format function, using the following format: dd-mmm-yyyy

The code I have for it so far is this:

```
Sub Req1()
  Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
  With NewBook
  .Title = "Table Data"
  Worksheets("2. Formatting").Activate
  Range("B3:R13").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(“Table Data”).Range(“A1”)
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Starks_Craig  Excel Assessment VBA\Starks_Craig  Excel Assessment VBA.xlsm" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
End Sub
```

The "Range("B3:R13").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(“Table Data”).Range(“A1”)" line appears in red as a compile error, and I'm not sure why. Also, I'm not entirely sure my code is comprehensive of this request. I'm asking for help since I'm pretty new to VBA.

Also, I am supposed to:

> 1. Create a button from the Developer tab so your manager can simply run your macro
> 2. Assign the button to the first subroutine you made
> 3. Repeat 1 and 2 for the second subroutine

Which I am unsure how to do because when I attempt to select the macro I made it gives me an error.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick, first answer: you have made a common mistake. 
It appears that you typed some of your code in a word processor
(like Microsoft Word) and copied it into the VBA editor:

```
  Range("B3:R13").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(“Table Data”).Range(“A1”)
        ↑      ↑                               ⇑          ⇑        ⇑  ⇑
          good                                      bad            bad
```

The first two quote characters are proper, code quotes. 
The last four quotes are word processing quotes, and cause errors in code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was a difference.